# Insert Microsoft Updates into Database

Tags: sql, powershell, updates

I'm trying to modify [this script](http://lyncdup.com/2013/09/list-all-microsoftwindows-updates-with-powershell-sorted-by-kbhotfixid-get-microsoftupdate/) so that it inserts the installed updates into an SQL Server database table.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=sqlserver; Initial Catalog=updates; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

$conn.Open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$wu = new-object -com “Microsoft.Update.Searcher”
$totalupdates = $wu.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$all = $wu.QueryHistory(0,$totalupdates)

$OutputCollection=  @()
Foreach ($update in $all){
 $Regex = “KB\d*”
$KB = $string | Select-String -Pattern $regex | Select-Object { $_.Matches }
$output = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$output | add-member NoteProperty “HotFix ID” -value $KB.‘ $_.Matches ‘.Value
  $output | add-member NoteProperty “Title” -value $string
$OutputCollection += $output
 $cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO dbo.updates (hotfixid, hotfixdescription) VALUES ('$($kb.'$_.Matches'.Value)', ('$($string)'))"
}

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.close()
```

At the moment, I'm getting correct number of rows for updates in sql server but it isn't showing hotfixid and in hotfix descriptien columns there is a only one update in all rows.

Thanks!

Comment: hotfixid i fixed myself. but thing what i can't get working is that every update is listed in sql not only first one

Answer (score 0):

Do the INSERTs inside the loop. I would, however, recommend that you use prepared statements instead of building the SQL statements via string concatenation. Also, there's no need to build `$OutputCollection` objects when you're not using it anywhere.

Something like this should work:

```
...
$wu.QueryHistory(0, $totalupdates) | % {
  $KB = $_.Title | ? { $_ -match '(KB\d+)' } | % { $matches[1] }

  $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
  $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.updates (hotfixid, hotfixdescription) " +
                     "VALUES (@id, @descr)"
  $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", $KB)
  $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr", $_.Title)
  $cmd.Prepare()
  $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
...
```

Untested, though, since I don't have an SQL Server at hand. I also suspect that there's a more efficient way to handle the prepared statements, but I'm not that familiar with SQL Server.